# Recover Chromium Edge session that couldn't reopen

Tags: chromium, microsoft-edge, browser-tabs, session-restore

I have it set to "continue where you left off" in the startup settings, but this time, it didn't. I had several windows with a total of over 1000 tabs. Whenever I started them up, they froze on white windows for several minutes. This time, I decided to terminate them in the middle of it and now it acted like those windows didn't exist. There's almost nothing in the "recently closed" menu and just one group/window of a few tabs. I tried running http://lsauer.net/chrome-session-restore/# but  I only got less than 500 listed. I ran this on Chrome because it's part of the linked thread's answer: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/msedge_search-msedge_win10/restore-previous-open-tabs-after-windows-update/bb061172-29fb-4060-a4f4-2d32d75b4458?page=2
[image]

There's also only "Sessions" and "Session Storage"
[image]

Comment: Drop back to yesterday's backup & start over.

Comment: try this : https://github.com/aljgom/chrome_sessions

Comment: @Madhubala Forgot to clarify that this is Microsoft Edge, which is also Chromium, but this link only applies to Google Chrome